# Dynamic routing in ASP.NET Core 3.1 when part of the url is already another route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-routing, dynamic-routing

I'm trying to use `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` with `IEndpointRouteBuilder.MapDynamicControllerRoute` to dynamically map new routes. This is for pages that are added while the application is running.

I'm doing:

```
endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<RouteValueTransformer>("{**slug}");
```

to catch *all* urls that don't already have a route assigned, so that `RouteValueTransformer` can try to find one when necessary. By putting a breakpoint inside the `RouteValueTransformer.TransformAsync` method, I can see when it runs. If you just type any nonsense url in, it will enter the method as expected. For a url that doesn't have a route assigned, but an earlier part of the url *does*, it *won't* enter the method, as it seems to think it already has a route, but then it obviously gives a 404 error.

For example, if after the above line I do

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
   name: "test",
   pattern: "category/product1",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

and then try to browse to "category/product2", I think it should enter the `TransformAsync` method to try and find a route, but it doesn't, and it gives a 404. If you change "category" to something else, it *will* enter the method.

I'm not sure if this is expected behaviour, a bug, or if I'm using the "pattern" parameter wrong, or maybe {**slug} wrong?

### To reproduce

It's very easy to reproduce. Create a new ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application. Add

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    var defaults = new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" };
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "test", pattern: "category/product1", defaults: defaults);
    endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<RouteValueTransformer>("{**slug}");
});
```

to the end of `Startup.Configure`,

```
services.AddSingleton<RouteValueTransformer>();
```

to `Startup.ConfigureServices`,
and

```
public class RouteValueTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer
{
    public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        return values;
    }
}
```

and set a breakpoint on `return values;` to see when it runs.

### What else I've tried

`endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<RouteValueTransformer>("{one}/{two}");` - also doesn't enter method.

Looking through documentation. There isn't much on `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` [(yet)](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/12997#) unfortunately so I've found it quite difficult.

### Update

I'm starting to think that it *is* mostly likely a bug, so I've raised [this Github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18688)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug and a fix is planned. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#conventional-routing-order

Comment: That "fix" wasn't very effective, though I forget the exact reasons why, and we ended up giving up with dynamic routing completely. I also don't know if anything has changed/improved in .NET 5+, so if anyone has a more up to date and comprehensive answer, I'll gladly change the accepted one from mine!